# What does it mean by the sub-clause "silently overflows to fit in a byte"?

Tags: php, regex, string, byte, octal

I'm using **PHP 7.2.2** on my **Windows10** Machine

I come across following statement from the PHP manual :

> *\[0-7]{1,3}*    : the sequence of characters matching the regular expression is a character in octal notation, which silently overflows
>   to fit in a byte (e.g. "\400" === "\000")

What does the above sentence mean? Especially, what does mean by the sub-clause "silently overflows to fit in a byte" and how the example given i.e.

> "\400" === "\000"

works and goes in sync with the statement given?

Link to the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Could you link to the documentation? There must be additional info, because I can't make any sense out of it.

Comment: @ClasG : Here is the link from the PHP Documentation : https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Comment: OK. That explains it. So GrowingBrick is correct, only didn't explain it in a way that made sense (to me).

Answer (score 2):

This kind of string escape should represent a single byte each, so you can't cast a number major than 255 in decimal to a single byte, instead it will take only lower 8 bits like doing `$number & 255` because the major value for a byte is 11111111 which represent 255 in decimal and 377 in octal

Comment: Huh...? This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It does, \400 is octal for 256 decimal which is 100000000 in binary so doing AND 255 (decimal) will result in 0 which is \000

Comment: How does it answer what the statement "*silently overflows to fit in a byte*" means? What you're saying isn't wrong, but I can't see how it answers the question.

Comment: The statement "silently overflows to fit in a byte", is only about the AND operation that takes only lower 8 bits, anything greater is stripped out and ignored

Comment: The Q is tagged with *string*, but I didn't notice that, and your answer didn't press on it either, so I couldn't understand it. Now that I've read the doc, and know it's about 8 bit string handling, it's obvious.